# update regression objects by passing an expression to "subset"

Tags: r, expression, substitution

I have many regression objects created by `lm()`. Each one has been built from a different data
frame, and these different data frames have different dimensions. But each data frame contains the logical variables `x`, `y`, and `z`. In some cases, I want to update each regression object so that the `subset` argument is `x`. In other cases, I want to update each regression object so that the `subset` argument is `y`. And in still other cases, I want to update each regression object so that the `subset` argument is `z`. What is an efficient way to do this?

This is the inefficient way:

```
# Set only one of these three variables to be TRUE
subsetX <- TRUE
subsetY <- FALSE
subsetZ <- FALSE

# Now update the regressions.
if (subsetX) {
  update(lm1, subset = x)
  update(lm2, subset = x)
  [...]
} else if (subsetY) {
  update(lm1, subset = y)
  update(lm2, subset = y)
  [...]
} else if (subsetZ) {
  update(lm1, subset = z)
  update(lm2, subset = z)
  [...]
}
```

This approach is inefficient because there is a lot of duplication across the three code blocks that update the regressions. I would rather do something like

```
subsetVar <- dplyr::case_when(
  subsetX ~ expression(x),
  subsetY ~ expression(y),
  subsetZ ~ expression(z))
update(lm1, subset = substitute(subsetVar))
update(lm2, subset = substitute(subsetVar))
[...]
```

That is, I would like to write at most one `update()` command for each
regression object, while still varying the `subset` argument on the basis of
logical (boolean) variables like `subsetX` and `subsetY`. Is this possible?
The code above doesn't work; when I try it, I get an `Error in xj[i] : invalid subscript type 'symbol'` error message.

I've searched other Stack Overflow questions, but I haven't found anything that speaks directly to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to make your workflow a little easier with a simple function and using `purrr::map2` to feed it the list of models and subsets you want

```r
library(purrr)
set.seed(2020)
mtcars$x <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 32, replace = TRUE)
mtcars$y <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 32, replace = TRUE)
mtcars$z <- sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), 32, replace = TRUE)

lm1 <- lm(mpg ~ hp, mtcars)


subset_lm_by <- function(model, subset = NULL) {
  if (subset == "x") {
    update(model, subset = x)
  } else if (subset == "y") {
    update(model, subset = y)
  } else if (subset == "z") {
    update(model, subset = z)
  } else {
#    cat('I only accept x, y or z!')
  }
}

models <- list(lm1, lm1, lm1, lm1)
subsets <- list("x", "y", "z", "nonsense")

purrr::map2(.x = models, 
            .y = subsets, 
            ~ subset_lm_by(model = .x, subset = .y))
#> [[1]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, subset = x)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    31.21178     -0.08098  
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, subset = y)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    32.83501     -0.07294  
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> 
#> Call:
#> lm(formula = mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars, subset = z)
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#> (Intercept)           hp  
#>    32.53554     -0.08688  
#> 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#> NULL
```